# Is Basis of a vector space a subset of the vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Now, I was going through my notes which says that basis of a vector space $V$ is a set $S$ such that

1. $S$ is a linearly independent set
2. $v=L(S)$

Now there might be multiple basis of a vector space. Hence many sets might be possible one of which includes a standard basis set.
I have a confusion:

1. Does the set has to be a subset of $V$ or it might not be a subset of $V$.
2. Is the above answer true if its a standard Basis of $V$?

Comment: A bsis of $V$ is  allways a subset of $V$.

Answer (score 2):

A basis is indeed a subset of its vector space.  The standard basis is a particular basis, of a nice form, that we all agree upon as standard.